# SwiftUI. How to place a view at the top of ZStack?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've tried this code and set alignment of the nested view to .top. But it's still cenetered.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle().fill(Color.red).frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 100, alignment: .top)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: For this job you do not need **Rectangle** use Color, see my code in answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do **not** need use **Rectangle** for this work, use **Color** instead, it make your View be cheaper/faster in render and less CPU than using Rectangle and then trying to fill it with Color.

---

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            
            Color.yellow
            
            VStack {
                
                Color.red.frame(height: 100)
                
                Spacer()
                
                Color.blue.frame(height: 100)
                
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: "it make your View be cheaper and much faster in render" -- do you have benchmark data that shows this is true? It would be surprising to me if this is actually the case.

Comment: Rectangle is a shape and logically take more process power to be created but Color is not shape and also it is primitive View, so defiantly cheaper to create for CPU

Comment: Either way, it’s getting rendered to the screen the same way — I definitely wouldn’t be convinced unless I saw benchmark data. I’d also be shocked if it had any effect even if it were true until hundreds if not thousands of instances.

Comment: You are right with this days CPU`s both are just nothing for cpu! But CPU would create a Rectangle shape first then start rendering with Color, so 2 step there!

Comment: SwiftUI is pretty far removed from what's really going on under the hood. You can't make any conclusions about which takes more processor time without testing, or at least analysis of the code that the compiler generates. I would not be at all surprised if the rectangle.fill.frame and the color.blue.frame approach generate exactly the same machine code.

Comment: @DuncanC: So what you would use if you wanted to have the same View and same result? Color or Rectangle?

Comment: Whichever makes the code more obvious. Probably Color, but only because it's a bit shorter, and many of us have internalized the SwiftUI idea that Color is "thing that fills a region." But if other teams found that confusing (and it is confusing), then I'd happily use Rectangle. There's no point where performance would enter into it, since it's almost certainly negligible.

Comment: @RobNapier: there is no point of using Rectangle in SwiftUI, any View that you think need and must be created with Rectangle, can be replaced with Color, even you can use Color instead of Circle and then clip it, So  it is up to you which works better to you, but for me and must people would be Color better choice instead of Rectangle.

Comment: Rob already answered the same way I would: Whatever made your intent and code clearer.

Comment: I would agree with that as well

Answer (score 2):

The surrounding `ZStack` needs to have a frame that will take up the whole view -- otherwise it'll just be the height of the rectangle.  It's also the one that needs the `.top` alignment:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(height: 100)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
    }
}
```

**Update, based on comment**:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.red)
                    .frame(height: 100)
                Spacer()
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.green)
                    .frame(height: 100)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to place one rectangle at the top and one at the bottom in the same ZStack?

Comment: Better suited to a `VStack` (which could be embedded in the `ZStack` -- see update.

Comment: The ZStack isn't doing anything here, though. It's precisely the size of the VStack. You can just remove it. (Same is true of the first example. A ZStack with one child doesn't do anything, since it will be exactly the same size as its child.)

Comment: Indeed -- it was left there with the supposition that there would be something the OP wanted on another layer.

Answer (score 2):

Another very direct way of doing it - you need a `GeometryReader` but to position the `x` not the `y`.

```
        GeometryReader { reader in
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill ( Color.red )
                    .frame ( height: h )
                    .position ( x: 0.5 * reader.size.width, y: 0.5 * h )
            }
        }
```

Here `h` is the desired height.

Comment: But why too much coding for simple thing? **GeometryReader** and **position** are really not needed here. Are we going make it easier or harder?

Comment: Agree - but just to show. If you e.g. have a fixed ```x``` this could be nice and you need not GeometryReader. Also, this does not use any other views e.g. no Spacers or other Rects so this may be the fastest?

Comment: As a way that this way exist I can understand, but it is like using atomic bomb for killing a fly!

Comment: lol ... no man, this is most direct. No other views needed so layout is no problem here. Clearly OP has a given height in mind so position is man for the job except for missing x. If that is known then use this, but reader should not be too much nuclear power ... lol

Answer (score 1):

The answers here are good, but it's worth diving into why you were confused in the first place. Let's look at your code:

```
ZStack {
    Rectangle()
        .fill(Color.red)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 100, alignment: .top)
}
```

This is a Rectangle, enclosed in a Fill, enclosed in a Frame, enclosed in a ZStack. Each of these is its own View.

First, the Rectangle declares that it will fill whatever space it is offered with a stroked and filled rectangle, using whatever stroke and fill color are set by its parents.

The Fill, which wraps the Rectangle, sets the fill color to red for its children.

The Frame offers "the lessor of what the Frame is offered and infinity" as the width and "the lessor of what the Frame is offered and 100" as the hight to its children. Its children (the Fill, which contains the Rectangle), accept all the space they're offered, which in the end will be "the width of the screen and 100 points high." The frame sets its own width to this, and aligns its one child at the top.

The ZStack offers the whole screen size to the Frame. When the Frame is done, the ZStack sets its own size to the size of its children (the Frame), and centers its children (since that's its alignment).

The containing View (which is the size of the screen), then centers the small ZStack.

The key point is that the `.top` applies to the *Frame*, not the ZStack, and not the entire View.

So how do you get what you want? First of all, you want the ZStack to be the size of the entire View. That means its *children* must be the size of the entire View.  A ZStack is *always* the exact size of its children.

But really, the natural way to do what you're describing is with a VStack, since you really want a vertical stack of views:

```
VStack {
    Rectangle().fill(Color.red).frame(height: 100)
    Spacer()
}
```

Or as Swiftpunk points out, you can use Color directly, though it's a trivial difference. It just is a little shorter in code. Setting the width here isn't meaningful.

```
VStack {
    Color.red.frame(maxHeight: 100)
    Spacer()
}
```

If you wanted a ZStack (I don't know why, but if you did), then you could achieve the same thing by forcing the ZStack to be as big as it's offered by including a Color, and then also ask it to align its elements at the topLeading.

```
ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
    Color.clear // Color is always as large as the space offered
    Color.red.frame(maxHeight: 100)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            Rectangle()
               .fill(Color.red)
               .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 100)
        }
    }
}
```